# Can't get backpack to pass correct value when inserting/updating a many to many relationship

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-backpack

I have created a many to many relationship between two tables with a third pivot table.
The thing that makes the situation a little difficult is I am linking the Apps table based on name and not ID.  It is because I update the App list from a third party and app name will always be consistent, where ID can possibly change if App is removed at some point, and then re-added, etc.

**Apps**

- id
- name   // This is the name of the app, it will never change for a particular app and is short, all lowercase, no spaces, and unique
- label  // This is the user friendly name

**Plans**

- id
- name
- etc

apps_plans pivot table

- id
- apps_name
- plans_id

I've finally got everything working perfectly in Laravel itself, but I cannot figure out at all how to get this to work correctly in Backpack for my Admin portal.  I've gotten it to the point where everything works perfect until I try to update or create a new plan.  The Apps I select using the select2 type, it tries to insert them into the pivot table with an ID number and not with the name.

Randomizing some names, my mistake if things don't match perfectly.  This aspect works fine from all tests I've done:

Plans Model:

```
{
    use CrudTrait;
    protected $table = 'plans';
    protected $guarded = ['id'];



    public function apps()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Apps', 'apps_plans', 'plans_id', 'apps_name', 'id', 'name');
    }
}
```

Apps Model:

```
    class Apps extends Model
{
    use CrudTrait;
    protected $table = 'apps';
    protected $guarded = ['id'];

    protected $casts = [
        'json' => 'array',
    ];

    public function plans()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Plan', 'apps_plans', 'apps_name', 'plans_id', 'name', 'id');
    }
}
```

**Note I removed the fillable variable , I didn't want to expose all variables in my columns.

Backpack Plans CrudController:

```
    public function setup()
    {
        CRUD::setModel(\App\Plan::class);
        CRUD::setRoute(config('backpack.base.route_prefix') . '/plan');
        CRUD::setEntityNameStrings('plan', 'plans');

        $this->crud->addColumn([
            'name' => 'apps',
            'type' => 'relationship',
            'label' => 'Apps',
            'entity' => 'apps',
            'attribute' => 'label',
            'model' => \App\Apps::class,
        ]);
    }


    protected function setupCreateOperation()
    {
        CRUD::setValidation(PlanRequest::class);

        CRUD::setFromDb(); // fields
       
        $this->crud->addField('apps', [
            'name' => 'apps',
            'type' => 'select2_multiple',
            'entity' => 'apps',
            'attribute' => 'label',
            'label' => 'Apps',
            'pivot' => true,
        ]);
```

I removed quite a bit to keep my project details private, I hope it makes sense.  I think all important details are still in.  Anyone know if this is an issue with Backpack?  Or did I miss an option somewhere, where you can set which column it uses for the relationship.  It is clearly not taking it from the model because the models work just as intended on their own...

Thanks!

Edit: here is my migration I am using, it works flawlessly--even in phpmyadmin it gives me a drop down of items to select from

```
    {
        Schema::create('apps_plans', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('apps_name');
            $table->foreign('apps_name')->references('name')->on('apps');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('plans_id');
            $table->foreign('plans_id')->references('id')->on('plans');
        });
    }
```

EDIT 2:

This is the error I am getting when trying to do a Create or Update:

```
{
"error": "There is a problem with your request",
"message": "SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`api`.`apps_plans`, CONSTRAINT `apps_plans_apps_name_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`apps_name`) REFERENCES `apps` (`name`)) (SQL: insert into `apps_plans` (`apps_name`, `plans_id`) values (2, 4))"
}
```

Again I removed some details that were very specific to my project but I don't think I changed any of the logic in the error message.  You can see everything looks great about the query except that at the very end, it is inserting the App ID instead of the App name as it should be.

Comment: I also have an auto incrementing id.  But let me try that

Comment: I tried that, it didn't help.  name isn't the primary key though, and I've seen numerous examples of the pivot table created with and without a separate auto incrementing ID

Comment: Hmm, what happens if you add `'model' => \App\Apps::class, // foreign key model` to the field config?

Comment: @WesleySmith Thanks for your comment.  While debuging yesterday I actually tried this and it is currently on my field.

I didn't notice this documentation at Backpack: https://backpackforlaravel.com/docs/4.1/crud-fields#optional-attributes-for-fields-containing-related-entries

After reviewing that thoroughly this morning, and trying a few more things, I think it is a bug in Backpack.

I never showed the exact error I am getting, although it is somewhat obvious, but I will do another edit on my question with error.

Comment: Im curious if you were to do something like, `$plan = Plan::find($somePlanId); $app = App::find($someAppId); $plan->apps()->attach($app);`, does that function as you expect?

Comment: @WesleySmith It does not.  In laravel tinker:

>>> $plan->apps()->attach($app);
=> null
>>>

Laravel docs says to use the "Id" of the 2nd table as the attach argument.  When I use an app name ->attach('tasks') I get the same null result.  When I use an Id from the Apps table, I get the same error as I am getting in Backpack

Comment: @WesleySmith It makes me think I need to make the app name a primary key in the apps table and ditch the auto increment ID.  I am going to try this now, if it works you can give an answer to this and I will set your answer as correct as it seams you led me towards the solution.  I am going to make the changes now and try

Comment: @WesleySmith  This did indeed work.  I'm happy to mark you as accepted answer if you just want to suggest making name the primary key.  I had to make a couple changes to my Model to have everything else still work properly, I can respond to your answer with those adjustments in case anyone else sees this in the future

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that the current configuration will have the same result in Laravel directly. ie running something like `$plan = Plan::find($somePlanId); $app = App::find($someAppId); $plan->apps()->attach($app);` would result in the same error.

Since `name` is the key that matters for the `apps` table, consider dropping the autoincrementing id for that table and instead setting

In the migration  for the apps table, do:

```
$table->string('name')->primary();
```

Then in your apps model, do:

```
protected $primaryKey = 'name';

public $incrementing = false;

protected $keyType = 'string';
```

Now, Laravel (and by proxy Backpack) should treat the relationship the way you expect.

Comment: Perfect solution.  I thought for sure this was backpack related, but with your troubleshooting method it easy to see it was not backpack related.